# What do they mean "Recording Ratio" in in the VLC Media Player, and what are the units (e.g. frames per second)?

Tags: keyframes, vlc

There exists a video-player known as [**VLC Media Player**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player).

My question is, for the scene video filter, what is the *recording ratio*?

If the number is **50** does that mean...

> - extract one frame every 50 seconds.
> - extract 50 frames per second.
> - extract 1 in 50 frames. Ignore the other 49 frames.

[image: animated GIF of graphic user interface option for "Recording Ratio" pulsating with yellow highlighting on and off, on and off ,on and off]

Comment: To digress.... computer programmers usually only write units such as millimeters, frames per second, meters, hours, pixels, etc... as ***comments***. ***comments*** in a programme in Java, C++, Python, etc... are always deleted when the code is converted into machine language (machine language is *mostly* ones and zeros for ALU instructions). Perhaps one day we will see some template class for putting scientific units on numeric data-types like whole numbered ***ints*** and decimal-numered ***floats***. For example, `record_ratio = Uni<float>(50, "fps")` instead of `record_ratio = float(50)`.